# iphone opengl proper set up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Last night I attempted to play around with OpenGL in Xcode, but I couldn't run it on my ipod 2nd Gen (error with Can't run 'FirstOpenGL' - was built for 'armv7', but device requires 'armv6' or compatible architecture).

The architecture option was only armv7 but there was no armv6. I opened it up with OpenGL template and I searched around build option but wasn't able to figure out how to set it up. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run on the simulator ?

Try changing the base SDK to something lower, see if that helps.

One last thing you could check is for this line:

```
EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2;
```

and change it to:

```
EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1;
```

Some old iPod cannot run OpenGL ES 2.0 so you need to use 1.1.

Comment: I think it automatically detects which version will be used, if device is not compatible with 2.0, it will change to 1.1. I don't think its the point here, I can't run on my ipod because there's no armv6 option on architecture.

Comment: meh nvm I didn't set target's build option to armv6 + armv7 =/